# tools for monitor android?

Tags: android, android-studio

in Android studio 2.x, the activity monitor does not require the app to be debuggable to be monitored, in recent versions, this seems not possible. is there any tool to monitor mem CPU network usage? just total over time graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CPU Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler). View > Tool Windows > Profiler or its tool button.

[image: screenshot]